# Format text file using shell

Tags: linux, shell, concatenation

I want to format text file using shell commands.

File content is like:

```
first_name:last_name:some_random_characters

Jack:Brown:!@#xyz
Mike:Spencer:234QWE
Robert:Junior:^#2dsa
...
```

and I want the output to be like:

```
JBrown:!@#xyz
MSpencer:234QWE
RJunior:^#2dsa
...
```

I tried using `cat -d ':' -f 1 file.txt` and `cat -d ':' -f 2-3 file.txt`,
but I don't know how to combine this commands.

Comment: I think you mean `cut`, not `cat`.

Comment: you combine commands by using pipes - https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html - they let u "stitch" output of previous command to become an input for the next. so for example, <cmd1> file1.txt | <cmd2> | <cmd3> ... ad infinitum

Comment: @MorganMLG : For removing the first two lines, I suggest to use `tail`. For recombining the fields of the lines, perhaps `awk` or `sed` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -E 's/(.)[^:]+:/\1/' file

JBrown:!@#xyz
MSpencer:234QWE
RJunior:^#2dsa
```

I think this is what you tried to do, but it's not efficient

```
$ paste -d'\0' <(cut -c1 file) <(cut -d: -f2- file)
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=":"}{print substr($1,1,1)$2, $3}' file.txt > outputfile.txt
```

This says:

1. Split each line by a colon (and also set the OFS-Output Field Separator as the same character) `BEGIN{OFS=FS=":"}`
2. Now print out the first character of the first column and all of the second column, a separator, and all of the third column `{print substr($1,1,1)$2, $3}`